# Adding FullCalendar to React on Rails project causes DoubleLinkError in application.css

Tags: fullcalendar, asset-pipeline, fullcalendar-5, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a React project served using Ruby on Rails 7. It's set up using [this tutorial](https://hibbard.eu/rails-react-crud-app) (source code available [here](https://github.com/jameshibbard/react-rails-crud-app)); I'm at the part where you [add React Router](https://hibbard.eu/rails-react-crud-app/#react-router) so you can add a second page to the app.

I ran `yarn add @fullcalendar/react @fullcalendar/daygrid` and created a new component:

```
import React from 'react';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

const Hoard = () => {
    return <div>
        <FullCalendar
            plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
        />
    </div>
}

export default Hoard;
```

Then when I run `./bin/dev` and load the page, I get this error:

[image: Sprockets::DoubleLinkError in application.css]

It seems that FullCalendar's CSS is somehow breaking Rails' asset pipeline. That doesn't make sense to me; FullCalendar doesn't have a file named application.css. Rails is creating app/assets/builds/application.css and then complaining that its filename conflicts with app/assets/stylesheets/application.css. This seems like a Rails problem instead of a FullCalendar problem, but it didn't come up until I added FullCalendar to the project. I can fix the problem by uninstalling FullCalendar, deleting my @node_modules folder, running `rake assets:clobber` and then `rake assets:precompile`.

Is this a FullCalendar problem or a Rails problem?